# Can Kendo TimezoneEditor be disabled?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler, kendo-template

Some controls (widgets?) in Kendo UI can be disabled using `data-bind="disabled:boundfield"`, some need to set this option manually (yes, it's about multiselect). 
But I can't find a good way to do this with TimezoneEditor — it not reacts on both. 
In Scheduler editor template I want to turn timezones to *readonly* state for some cases (a.e. occurrence events), but can't find a proper solution.

Comment: I don't think you can...

Comment: No way there? That's strange.

Comment: I agree that there does not appear to be an easy provided option to solve this. I would recommend providing a jsfiddle or kendo dojo with your situation so that people could look for a workaround.

Comment: the best solution in this case would be to listen to the change and update events and just to prevent the default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, TimezoneEditor can't be disabled in current version, so we just replaced it with custom selector.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely turn off the time zones, there are some steps over here in this link [completely-turn-them-off](http://www.telerik.com/forums/time-zones---completely-turn-them-off)

I did not test it as i am new to kendoUI, but it may help you in finding some way.

Comment: Nope. This is not what I searching.